# How to proper auto scale ToolStrip in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, scaling, highdpi

I am struggling to solve the following issue and I am wondering if someone can help.

I am building a .NET C# WinForm app targeting .NET 4.6 which should have improved high DPI support. I am developing the app on my laptop which features 4K screen and has scaling set to 200% in Windows 10.

My app calls SetHighDPIAware and has in app.config

```
<add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
```

set.
The issue is: when i add a Toolstrip it shows correctly on my PC but doubled in size (only the images) on my customer PC. The result is very ugly.
All properties of ToolStrip and ToolStrip items are set to default: autosize = true, imagescaling size = 32; 32, imagescalingmode = sizetofit.

Thanks a lot to anyone could help!

[image: UP: my pc DOWN: customer PC]

Comment: There is little you can do (unless you fully draw the control yourself). Microsoft might have resolved that in .NET Framework 4.6.2 (or in future releases, such as 4.6.3), so you might check that first.

Answer (score 0):

Update to [Windows 10 v1703 (Creators Update)](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/03/29/windows-10-creators-update-coming-april-11-surface-expands-markets/) and target your application to [.Net framework 4.7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/) in Visual Studio 2017 to have [better DPI scaling support](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/Introducing-Windows-Forms-HDPI-Improvements-in-NET-Framework-47) in WinForms.

Try if this gives you an improvement.

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know.

Comment: ok, do this and report back. Here are also [additional information about HighDPI in Winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt799789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry. No improvements. Tried even creating a blank project on vs 2017, targeting fw 4.7, doing all tweaks to app.manifest and app.config, running on win 10 creators update, but no improvements, even with the simplest toolstrip with 1 button in it.

Comment: this is wired. The documentation [mentions ToolStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt492940%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). set **Toolstrip.DisableHighDpiImprovements** to **false** in app.config. also add supportedOS guid of Win10 to manifest

Comment: Toolstrip.DisableHighDpiImprovements defaults to false. Don't worry, I've done everything specified in the documentation. Maybe Microsoft haven't thought of apps designed at high dpi and run at low dpi.

Comment: can you share your small demo (github) and I'll try it on my own

Comment: actually, even HiDPI sample from dotnet-samples does not scale toolstrip added there :(